# Read file and count same entries in Java

Tags: java

I need some advice. I know how to solve this problem clumsily, but I want to do it the *right* way, as I need to impress someone for a potential internship.

I have a textfile, for example:

```
[XXX622] [YYY]  [LLL]   [E77700]  [NNN]  [6JL99NNN] [HH66]  [0770LLL]  [R88] [VVV]
[B177HQ] [8RR22]   [PPP]  [GGG]  [CCXXXGG]   [8IIXX0] [3KCC]   [00222]
[222] [OO] [OO] [OO] [99]   [555444]   [33]
```

I need to read the entries and then do processes with them, for example sort alphabetically.

The process I don't know how to do is counting how many similar entries are in each line.

If I read the entries into a string array and pass the array to the counting method, then how should I make it so the method knows from which line each entry is? Should I create a 2D array and insert the linenumber along with the entry into it as a string?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use the elements indexes as line numbers.

Comment: "I need to impress someone"... if other people answer, then it won't be you impressing them really, it will be other people!

Comment: What do you mean by "similar" ? Whats your desierd output?

Comment: are you trying to sort alphabetically and uniquely?

Comment: You won't impress him if you tell him you just asked for the solution on StackOverflow :-)

Comment: well, ask the community is not a bad thing for me, assuming, of course, that he tried something first.

Comment: @ Kal, by "similar" I meant "same". Check how many of the entries are the same.
@ Sai, I already have sorting alphabetically done, need to count how many same ones are on each line. to move on now

Comment: @bluefoot - I agree, but the fact that the OP says "I need to impress someone" and proceeds to ask for help, to me, is a big no. What would you say to a potential employee who gave you an answer you knew they had obtained from the community rather than written yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint.

Use a `Map` (some concrete implementation thereof; `HashMap` would work) when you process the line. If you know how to insert an entry into a `Map`, and if you know how to tell if an entry already exists in the `Map`, you have your solution!

If you really want to impress them  explain to them why the `Map` solution is fast and then also explain the speed vs. memory trade-offs. Using Big-O notation will impress them more and will also show that you know what you're talking about.

I'm not going to give you the entire (working) solution since you said this was for an internship. If your intent is to impress them, you should work out the solution yourself. Presenting a community solution as your own would be a little dishonest, in my opinion.

Comment: I figured if I learn the right solution (with help), then it won't be dishonest, because I know the solution when I'm doing work for them.
 But yeah, I get what you mean.

Comment: With the hint I've given you, you should be able to make significant headway. The meat of your algorithm is separating the line into individual codes, and then looking at each code and figuring out if you've already encountered it before. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few good options. The simplest would be to simply read the entries in and process them one line at a time, rather than all at once. Another option would be to create a class that represents a line:

```
public class CodeLine {
    public int lineNumber;
    public List<string> codes;
}
```

This is a more "object-oriented" way to represent your lines, as opposed to a 2D array.

Comment: Like use a constructor for a line? That's a great idea, man! I'm probably going to do that, thanks, but going to read up on Map and HashMap first.

Comment: Yeah, the idea is to represent the ideas that you want to represent with "objects." Using a Map/Hashmap is a strategy you could use in addition to (not instead of) this approach (Though I'd recommend a HashSet instead).